# SQLitePlugin: org.json.JSONException: No value for qid

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I am trying to use ionic 1.7.16 with Cordova SQLitePlugin (https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) for Android. As per the example at (https://github.com/litehelpers/Ionic-sqlite-database-example) the code I wrote is as follows:

```
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'test.db', location: 'default' }, function () {
        alert("DB opened");
        db.transaction(function (tr) {
            tr.executeSql("SELECT upper('Test string') AS upperString", [], function (tr, rs) {
                console.log('Got upperString result: ' + rs.rows.item(0).upperString);
            });
        });//end transaction 
        alert("after Transaction");
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id integer primary key, firstname text, lastname text)");
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('Open database ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
    );//end openDatabase
}); //end addEventListener
```

I am able to see all the alerts, but no output from console.log. I do not see any error when opening the database, but I see in logcat, an error when transaction is executed. The error is:

```
unexpected error
org.json.JSONException: No value for qid
at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
at org.pgsqlite.SQLitePlugin.executeAndPossiblyThrow(SQLitePlugin.java:145)
at org.pgsqlite.SQLitePlugin.execute(SQLitePlugin.java:82)
at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:97)
at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:132)
at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemExposedJsApi.exec(SystemExposedJsApi.java:41)
at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:53)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xf3e17160
```

I am unable to find any help online. I tested my code on both an android device (One Plus One, sdk 23) and genymotion virtual device (google nexus api 23).

Comment: This SQl seems a little weird : `SELECT upper('Test string') AS upperString`. You don't specify a table. Furthermore, the request are async so it is normal that it prints alert. For transaction and the first execute, you don't specify an error callback function that is why maybe you don't have any errors an console.